# How to fix this schema markup, I am getting the error code Duplicate key found

Tags: schema

Can you please help me fix this Schema markup. When testing on Google Structured Data Testing tool, I am getting the error code:

> Duplicate key found in object declaration on line 119

```
<!-- JSON-LD markup generated by Google Structured Data Markup Helper. -->
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context" : "http://socialwetalk.me",
  "@type" : "LocalBusiness",
 "name" : "SocialWeTalk",
  "image" : [ "http://socialwetalk.me/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/macbook_mockup-1.png", "http://socialwetalk.me/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/service-summary-2.png" ],
"priceRange" : "$450 - $850",
  "telephone" : "+961 76 020 274",
  "email" : "info@socialwetalk.me",
  "address" : {
    "@type" : "PostalAddress",
    "streetAddress" : "Hamra, Jeanne d'Arc",
    "addressLocality" : "Beirut"
  },
  "geo" : {
    "@type" : "GeoCoordinates",
    "latitude" : "33.897835",
    "longitude" : "35.481523"
  },
"@type":"Review",
"itemReviewed":{"@type":"Product","name":"SocialWeTalk"}
"reviewRating":{"@type":"Rating","ratingValue":4.5,"bestRating":5}
"author":{"@type":"Person","name":"Samir Tutunji"}
"reviewBody":"SocialWeTalk helped us understand where our customers are coming from, and came up with an innovative concept online to keep them coming..."}
}
</script>
```

I am using **Google Structured Data** testing tool to validate my work

Answer (score 0):

Its fixed and reformatted

```
<!-- JSON-LD markup generated by Google Structured Data Markup Helper. -->
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context" : "http://schema.org",
  "@type" : "LocalBusiness",
  "name" : "SocialWeTalk",
  "image" : [ "http://socialwetalk.me/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/macbook_mockup-1.png", "http://socialwetalk.me/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/service-summary-2.png" ],
  "priceRange" : "$450 - $850",
  "telephone" : "+961 76 020 274",
  "email" : "info@socialwetalk.me",
  "address" : {
    "@type" : "PostalAddress",
    "streetAddress" : "Hamra, Jeanne d'Arc",
    "addressLocality" : "Beirut"
  },
  "review" : [
    {
    "@type" : "Review",
    "author" : {
      "@type" : "Person",
      "name" : "Pro Retrofits"
    },
    "reviewBody" : "We love our clients"
  }, {
    "@type" : "Review",
    "author" : {
      "@type" : "Person",
      "name" : "Crunch"
    },
    "reviewBody" : "We love our clients"
    }, {
    "@type" : "Review",
    "author" : {
      "@type" : "Person",
      "name" : "SocialWeTalk"
    }],
  "geo" : {
    "@type" : "GeoCoordinates",
    "latitude" : "33.897835",
    "longitude" : "35.481523"
  }
  }
 </script>
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context":"http://socialwetalk.me","@type":"Review",
    "itemReviewed":{"@type":"Product","name":"SocialWeTalk"},
    "reviewRating":{"@type":"Rating","ratingValue":4.5,"bestRating":5},
    "author":{"@type":"Person","name":"Samir Tutunji"},
    "reviewBody":"SocialWeTalk helped us understand where our customers are coming from, and came up with an innovative concept online to keep them coming..."}
</script>
```